# How to check if you are in a Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am creating a python module with a function to display a pandas DataFrame (`my_df`).

If the user imports the module into a Jupyter notebook, I would want to deliver "pretty" formatting for the DataFrame by using something like:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(my_df)
```

If the user is not in a Jupyter notebook, I would want to display the text form of the DataFrame:

```
print(my_df)
```

How can I check if the code is being run from a Jupyter notebook? Or, how can I display the DataFrame in text form from the commandline, vs display the HTML form if it is imported into a Jupyter notebook?

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML

def my_func(my_df):
    if [... code to check for Jupyter notebook here ...]:
        display(my_df)
    else:
        print(my_df)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need to check if the code is being run from a Notebook; `display()` prints text when called from the command line.

`test.py`:

```
from IPython.display import display
import pandas as pd 

my_df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[1,2,3],'bar':[7,8,9]})
display(my_df)
```

From the command line:

```
$ python test.py 
   bar  foo
0    7    1
1    8    2
2    9    3
```

From a Jupyter Notebook:

[image: notebook printout]

**UPDATE**
To check whether you're running inside an interactive Ipython shell (command-line or browser-based), check for `get_ipython`. (Adapted from the [Ipython](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/reference.html) docs)

Modified `test.py`:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
import pandas as pd 
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[1,2,3],'bar':[7,8,9]})

try:
    get_ipython
    display(my_df)
except:
    print(my_df)
```

This approach will:
- pretty-print in a browser Jupyter notebook
- print text when run as a script from the command line (e.g. `python test.py`)
- if run line-by-line in a Python shell, it will not turn into an interactive Ipython shell after printing

Comment: In an interactive python shell, this turns the entire shell into a Jupyter notebook style CLI.

Comment: That's true - you didn't mention anything in your post about running from an interactive python shell.  From a simple command line call it works as desired.

Comment: See my updated answer for addressing the interactive CLI issue.

Comment: One shouldn't use a try/except to control logic and this actually never fails in CLI, so it just doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

You should look in os.environ.

On my machine you can see it in

```
os.environ['_']
```

Comment: Some shells will set the _ environment variable to be the last process run.  While this might work, it's not really reliable and I suspect there's a better answer than depending on this.